# Xcode 3.2 doesn't display images on Interface Builder

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, xcode

I'm trying to use Xcode for the first time in my life (because i've used Visual Studio, Visual Studio Code etc.).

I wan't to create a tool that creates bootable USB for Hackintosh, and i want to use images as buttons in the main Window using Interface Builder, but it doesn't display the image i chose.

[image]

Using Xcode 3.2 on OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm really not sure what led you to believe you need Xcode to make a USB macOS installer, but as Hackintosh is off-topic here the point becomes moot. btw, you won't get a PC to boot off a regular macOS install USB stick anyway, without  a lot of extra effort. That aside, Snow Leo is the equivalent of WinXP… of use to neither man nor beast these days.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the use of macOS on non-Apple hardware is a legal grey area and as a result "Hackintosh" questions have been deemed [off-topic](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/1471/are-hackintosh-questions-allowed).